# Add quantity field with each product which contain particular quatity as per user added product into the cart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, opencart2.x

I added a quantity box near add to cart button for particular product added in cart.  Initially it is zero.  As user/customer adds a product to cart, its size should increase one by one.

File `template/module/feature.tpl`

```
<button class="product-btn-add" type="button" onclick="cart.minus('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');pq_minus( $(this).parent() );">
    <span class="hidden-sm">-</span>
</button>
<input class="product-quantity-input" type="text"  text-align="center" value="0" size="1" readonly="true">
<button class="product-btn-add" type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');pq_plus( $(this).parent() ); ">
    <span class="hidden-sm">+</span>
</button>
```

common.js

```
function pq_setQuantity( $input, add ) {
    var val = pq_getQuantity( $input );
    val += 1 * ( add ? 1 : -1 );
    if( val < 1 )
        val = 0;
    input.attr('value', val.toString()).val( val.toString() );
}               

function pq_getQuantity( $input ) { 
    var val = parseInt( $input.val() );
    if( typeof val == 'NaN' || val < 1 )
        val = 0;
    return val;
}

function pq_plus( $item ) {
    pq_setQuantity( $item.find('.product-quantity-input'), true );
}

function pq_minus( $item ) {
    pq_setQuantity( $item.find('.product-quantity-input'), false );
}
```

When i refresh the page,the quantity text input box becomes zero

[image]
I have add two picture before refresh and after refresh
[image]

Comment: And where is your code that does the storing of these values?

Comment: @Naruto i am using Opencart 2.x , i am not storing value,that is the problem, opencart already storing it somewhere ,but i am unable to get that in "featured".

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch cart info from cart class `system/library/cart.php`

try `print_r($this->cart->getProducts());`

here you can find `product_id` and associated `added quantity` of your cart
. Now you can pass associated added quantity to your view file form controller.

Good Luck